# Spark Structured Streaming: Writing DataFrame as CSV fails because of a missing watermark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I am using

- Spark, version 3.4.1
- PySpark, version 3.4.1
- Python, version 3.11

Using Spark Structured Streaming I want to write a DataFrame as CSV file.

`logsDF` is a `pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame` with the schema:

```
root
 |-- timestampLog: string (nullable = true)
 |-- status: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- timestampProcessing: timestamp (nullable = false)
```

The Python code generates the error message that a watermark is required although a watermark is specified.

How can I fix it?

```py
statusCountsDF = logsDF \
    .withWatermark("timestampProcessing", "10 minutes") \
    .groupBy(
        window(logsDF.timestampProcessing, "10 minutes"),
        logsDF.status
    ).count()

query = (statusCountsDF.writeStream
         .outputMode("append")
         .format("csv")
         .option("path", "logs/result")
         .option("header", True)
         .option("checkpointLocation", "logs/checkpoint")
         .queryName("counts")
         .start())

query.awaitTermination()
```

**Error**

```
pyspark.errors.exceptions.captured.AnalysisException: Append output mode not supported when there are streaming aggregations on streaming DataFrames/DataSets without watermark;
Aggregate [window#15, status#3], [window#15 AS window#9, status#3, count(1) AS count#14L]
+- Project [named_struct(start, knownnullable(precisetimestampconversion(((precisetimestampconversion(timestampProcessing#4, TimestampType, LongType) - CASE WHEN (((precisetimestampconversion(timestampProcessing#4, TimestampType, LongType) - 0) % 600000000) < cast(0 as bigint)) THEN (((precisetimestampconversion(timestampProcessing#4, TimestampType, LongType) - 0) % 600000000) + 600000000) ELSE ((precisetimestampconversion(timestampProcessing#4, TimestampType, LongType) - 0) % 600000000) END) - 0), LongType, TimestampType)), end, knownnullable(precisetimestampconversion((((precisetimestampconversion(timestampProcessing#4, TimestampType, LongType) - CASE WHEN (((precisetimestampconversion(timestampProcessing#4, TimestampType, LongType) - 0) % 600000000) < cast(0 as bigint)) THEN (((precisetimestampconversion(timestampProcessing#4, TimestampType, LongType) - 0) % 600000000) + 600000000) ELSE ((precisetimestampconversion(timestampProcessing#4, TimestampType, LongType) - 0) % 600000000) END) - 0) + 600000000), LongType, TimestampType))) AS window#15, timestampLog#2, status#3, timestampProcessing#4-T600000ms]
   +- Filter isnotnull(timestampProcessing#4)
      +- EventTimeWatermark timestampProcessing#4: timestamp, 10 minutes
         +- Project [regexp_extract(value#0, \[(\d{2}/\w{3}/\d{4}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} \+\d{4})], 1) AS timestampLog#2, cast(regexp_extract(value#0, \s(\d{3})\s, 1) as int) AS status#3, 2023-07-05 20:39:13.000826 AS timestampProcessing#4]
            +- StreamingRelation DataSource(org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@12625ab6,text,List(),None,List(),None,Map(wholetext -> false, path -> logs/),None), FileSource[logs/], [value#0]
```

Answer (score -3):

Can you try setting the mode to complete and see if it helps ?

```py
statusCountsDF = logsDF \
    .withWatermark("timestampProcessing", "10 minutes") \
    .groupBy(
        window(logsDF.timestampProcessing, "10 minutes"),
        logsDF.status
    ).count()

query = (statusCountsDF.writeStream
         .outputMode("complete")  # Change output mode to "complete"
         .format("csv")
         .option("path", "logs/result")
         .option("header", True)
         .option("checkpointLocation", "logs/checkpoint")
         .queryName("counts")
         .start())

query.awaitTermination()
```

The "complete" mode allows the entire updated result table to be written to the output at every trigger interval.

If needed you can adjust the output mode and watermark settings according to your specific requirements.

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT

Comment: And now changed to obfuscate it.

Comment: I know that Chat-GPT suggest the "complete" mode, but PySpark raises an error: pyspark.errors.exceptions.captured.AnalysisException: Data source csv does not support Complete output mode.